# Как задать высоту UICollectionView?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

У меня есть на одном ViewController несколько UICollectionView. Я хочу, чтобы CollectionView(оранжевого цвета) имела такую высоту, чтобы все ячейки помещались в CollectionView (и получается, что ViewController будет получать динамическую высоту, в зависимости от количества элементов в CollectionView)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока что, я установил в ручную размер ViewController и размер UICollectionView(оранжевого цвета).

Comment: Почему белую область не сделать частью UICollectionView? Или же зачем делать оранжевую часть фиксированной, если она для того и UICollectionView, чтобы скроллить?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы при листании вниз, верхних элементов не было. Поэтому и растягиваю UICollectionView! А вот на счет того, чтобы сделать это все одной CollectionView я и не додумался.. Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: через констрейнт можно задать